# how to calculate grand total of multiple using jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my script how to calculate grand total from the multiple values, I'm using table with autocomplete form add delete rows.

My script:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    $("table").on("change", "input", function() {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var qty = parseFloat(row.find(".quantity").val());
        var price = parseFloat(row.find(".productprice").val());
        var tcost = qty * price;
        row.find(".tcost").val(isNaN(tcost) ? "" : tcost);


    });
    if (!isNaN(tcost))
        total += tcost;
    $("#total").html("EUR " + total);
    row.find(".total").val(isNaN(total) ? "" : total);
})();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

$("select").change(function() {
    var qty = $(this).val();

```
// get the price cell by moving up a level and searching for
// the descendant with a class name beginning with `price'.
// Remove the dollar sign to do math
var price = $(this).closest("tr")
                   .find("td[class^=price]")
                   .html().split("$")[1];

// a quantity is a whole number but a price is a float
var total = parseInt(qty) * parseFloat(price);

// write the total for this book to the 'total' cell
$(this).closest("tr")
       .find("td[class^=total]")
       .html("$" + total);

// sum up all the totals
var grandTotal = 0;
$("td[class^=total]").each(function() {
    grandTotal += parseFloat($(this).html().split("$")[1]); 
});

// update the grandtotal cell to the new total
$(".grandtotal").html("$" + grandTotal);
```

});​

In other words, you need to:

1 - Get the quantity from the selected option's value.

2 - Get the price from the cell in the same row whose class begins with 'price', multiply that by the quantity, and update the 'total' cell of the same row.

3 - (Re)calculate the grand total (the sum of all totals) and put that value into the .grandtotal cell.

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kYssr/4/